# How to solve a duplicate column name error in web2py

Tags: mysql, web2py

I'm running web2py on pythonanywhere. I've started getting a duplicate column name error when the db.py file runs. I've tried restoring the database from a backup and also dropping the table and adding it back, without success.  At this point I'm completely locked out of my app.

I've tried removing all but the last field in the table, but then the problem appears in the next table.

I'm wondering if web2py uses a cache that needs to be cleared.

Here is the relevant portion of my db.py file:

```
db.define_table('library',
            Field('title', 'string'),
            Field('created','datetime'),
            Field('duration','float'),
            Field('error_message','string'),
            Field('external_id','string'),
            Field('hosting_type','string'),
            Field('source_id','string', unique = True),
            Field('last_modified','datetime'),
            Field('media_type','string'),
            Field('mime_type','string'),
            Field('relationships','string'),
            Field('source_schema','string'),
            Field('source_url','string'),
            Field('status','string'),
            Field('trim_in_point','string'),
            Field('trim_out_point','string'),
            Field('source_type','string'),
            Field('poster','string'),
            Field('background_poster_filename','string'),
            Field('background_poster','upload', required=False, requires = IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IMAGE(extensions=('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'), maxsize=(1920, 1080)))),
            Field('sources','list:string',length = 4096),
            Field('tracks','string'),
            singular="Library",
            plural="Library"
           )
```

Here is the error ticket:

```
Ticket ID
67.0.14.100.2022-06-23.16-49-09.ecf75fd3-1bb4-4f76-b557-95e072c6681f

<class 'gluon.contrib.pymysql.err.InternalError'> (1060, "Duplicate column name 'title'")
Version
web2py™ Version 2.21.1-stable+timestamp.2020.11.28.04.10.44
Python  Python 3.7.10: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi (prefix: /home/ghdev/.virtualenvs/ghdevvirtualenv)
Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
exec(ccode, environment)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/applications/ghrokucms/models/db.py", line 283, in <module>
plural="Library"
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 660, in define_table
table = self.lazy_define_table(tablename, *fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 701, in lazy_define_table
polymodel=polymodel,
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 920, in create_table
return self.migrator.create_table(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/migrator.py", line 376, in create_table
fake_migrate=fake_migrate,
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/migrator.py", line 544, in migrate_table
self.adapter.execute(sub_query)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/__init__.py", line 69, in wrap
return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 468, in execute
rv = self.cursor.execute(command, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py", line 835, in query
self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py", line 1019, in _read_query_result
result.read()
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py", line 1302, in read
first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py", line 981, in _read_packet
packet.check_error()
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/ghdev/web2py/gluon/contrib/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)
gluon.contrib.pymysql.err.InternalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'title'")
```

I'm at a loss to figure how to resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. In addition to dropping the table, I needed to delete the associated file in the web2py database directory. I then had to manually add back the table to the mySql database.

SOLVED.